# I restricted my own access to a partition on my computer. How do I get access again?

Tags: windows-8

The OS is Windows 8 Pro.

In an attempt to block another user I just created, I removed access for myself from an entire partition.

Now, there is no option of assigning access to myself again and I can't call myself a pro in this regard, so I'm basically locked out of my own partition.

I have access to the admin account on the computer, which is basically my main account. What am I supposed to do? I am pretty sure there is a simple way out since I am the admin, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your admin account you can take 'ownership' of a file, folder, drive etc and then reassign your account the permissions you want (eg. full control etc)

Check this link on how to add the Take ownership option to the context menu: [Add Take ownership to context menu in Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2814-take-ownership-add-context-menu-windows-8-a.html)

And this link on taking ownership [How to take ownership of a file, folder etc](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2808-take-ownership-file-folder-drive-registry-key-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: Did it, but nothing changed afterwards, still can't find a way to grant access to myself

Comment: Check this link for setting permissions. Once you've taken ownership you should be able to set the permissions for your user account. Link: --> http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2815-permissions-allow-deny-access-users-groups-windows-8-a.html